# Blender 2.8 slow render under mesa-18.3.2 and xvfb

Tags: rendering, opengl

How I can profile timings in Blender 2.8 Eevee engine rendering process?

I have blender 2.8 (nightly build) running inside docker container, with mesa-18.3.2 (build from sources) and gallium driver set to llvmpipe. OS: Ubuntu 18.10.

Under same docker container I test 2.79 and 2.8
Times differs 10x. 
2.79: Time: 00:07.76 (Saving: 00:01.57)
2.80: Time: 01:12.40 (Saving: 00:02.29)

Too big difference here. Any ideas what should I check?

Thank you!

Comment: llvmpipe is a software renderer. Eevee (realtime renderer) however utilises the 3D/OpenGL capabilities of GPU for rendering, and doing that via a software rasteriser (llvmpipe) is even slower than rendering it with the CPU renderer (as you did with <=2.79). Instead of Eevee, use the normal renderer in 2.80, just as you did before with older versions.

Answer (score 1):

As was said by @Ignatiamus blender 2.80 heavily depends on GPU.
So after putting blender onto machine with GPU it starts working fast even inside docker.